# Save bitmap to png with medata data wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, png

I need to save a bitmap to jpg with medata like copyright in wpf c#.

```
         var  handle = BitmapImage2Bitmap(currentimage).GetHbitmap();



        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(handle);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem prop = img.PropertyItems[0];
        SetProperty(ref prop, 33432, "Copyright");
        img.SetPropertyItem(prop);

        


        img.Save(@"C:\images\test.jpg");
```

I already tried using the code above but it says that the index was out of the arrayarea.

Comment: In future please read the docs first

Comment: `System.Drawing.Image` is WinForms, not WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var prop = img.GetPropertyItem(0x503B);
prop.Value = Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes("copyright name");
prop.Len = prop.Value.Length;
img.SetPropertyItem(prop);
```

The value 0x503B comes from here:
[PropertyItem.Id Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)